# jQuery toggling a class within a specific form

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a click function which toggles the wording of some text within a form. This same area/wording appears multiple times within my javascript application.

In an effort to make my code cleaner, I figured it would make sense if I only had this toggle code block once. Consequently, I feel like I need to toggle based on the relevant form the user is on.

Here's my code.. Is there a way I can pass a form name to this in order just to affect the form the user is currently viewing and not the other instances of the classes in my application?

```
$("#.myLink").click(function(){
$("#myContainer").toggle();
$(this).text($(this).text() == 'Add' ? 'Remove' : 'Add');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can pass a form name to this in order just to affect
>   the form the user is currently viewing and not the other instances of
>   the classes in my application?

You can use:

```
$(this).closest('form')
```

To get the form user is on. You can also assign your form to a variable if you want:

```
var $frm = $(this).closest('form');
// do something with $frm
```

Comment: Thanks blaster, this worked - will mark as answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: BTW - anyway to make that toggle code more efficient? Seems weird I need 3 states in there versus just 2?

Comment: @JasonWells: seems fine to me :)

Comment: One more thing blaster.. this doesn't seem to be working properly. Anything I am missing.

frmID = "#" + $(this).closest('form').attr("id"); 
$(frmID +"> #myContainer").toggle();

Comment: @JasonWells: I dont get where `currentForm` is coming from but try this instead: `$("#myContainer", $(this).closest('form')).toggle();`

Comment: `var frm = $(this).closest('form'); $("#myContainer", frm).toggle();`